# Python TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if this is a basic question, but I'm getting a Type Error, while trying to access values in a pandas dataframe.

The error is:

> TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on < class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [1] of < type 'sage.rings.integer.Integer'>

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
            'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
            'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32')})
print df.iloc[1]
```

Most likely I just don't understand how to use iloc correctly; can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message notes, you're not using a standard Python integer with `iloc` but rather, something from [Sage](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/index.html). So pandas doesn't recognise it as being a Python integer.

So if you have done something like

```
si = sage.all.Integer(1)  # or loading a sage script
# ... some lines of pandas
df.iloc[si]  # won't work
df.iloc[int(si)]  # casts from a Sage type to a Python type.
```

And if you're running it as a `.sage` script and not a Python script, then postfix an `r` to prevent it being converted to a Sage type:

```
df.iloc[1r]
```

See [this answer from the sagemath forums](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/35270/sage-vs-python-integers-and-floats-in-pandas-matplotlib-etc/?answer=35273#post-id-35273) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code but changed the last line because I am using Python 3. I didn't see a problem here.

```
print(df.iloc[1])
```

This output:

```
A                      1
B    2013-01-02 00:00:00
C                      1
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Same here. I think the OP is using something from http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/index.html